# Remote Desktop Printing Issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, printing

We have a remote non-AD application server running Windows 2008 R2. Users are logging in via RDP and attempting to print Word documents (Word 2007) to their local printer and from time to time if the document is more than 1 or 2 pages, the Print Spooler service becomes unresponsive and I am forced to stop the service and start it again, at which time printing commences to some degree of success.

Recently, this has stopped working. Today I have had to restart the print spooler service for each and every print job redirected to the client computer. For larger print jobs (more than 5 pages), I can see the server spool to the client, and then on the local machine it will lock up after spooling approximately half the document (in KB). When I restart the spooler service locally, clear the queue and print a test page, half the print job that I cancelled sputters out of the printer, along with a page somewhere in the middle that is half-printed -- assuming this is the "half-spooled" print job.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Printing to Redirected printers, local printers, or what?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've got a bad driver in there. Remove all of them and try configuring the Terminal Services Easy Print driver, via local policy

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753853(v=ws.10).aspx